# Finding common values between three or more dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, inner-join

Im working with R Studio Version 1.0.143.

I would like to make a new data frame which only includes rows that are common to AT LEAST two data frames, from multiple data frames. Problem is: I must know where the common data is too!

I'm trying with the following code, but some values are not being recognized as common!

```
library (readxl)
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- read_excel("Sample 1.xlsx")
df2 <- read_excel("Sample 2.xlsx")
df3 <- read_excel("Sample 3.xlsx")
lst(df1,df2,df3) %>%
bind_rows(.id='df') %>%
filter(GENE %in% unique(GENE[duplicated(GENE)])) %>%
mutate(df2=df) %>%
spread(df,df2) -> final
```

The example is the following:

data.frame 1

```
SITE    GENE
UTR3    MRPL30
UTR3    CASP10
exonic  PPIL3
UTR3    ZNF154
exonic  MET10
UTR3    CRCP
UTR3    CYP20A1
UTR3    PDDC1
UTR3    MET10
```

data.frame 2

```
SITE    GENE
UTR3    ZNF154
UTR3    MET10
UTR3    EFHC1
UTR3    SLC11A2
UTR3    SNX22
UTR3    MET10
```

data.frame 3

```
SITE    GENE
UTR3    KIAA1143
UTR3    AAK1
UTR3    EFHC1
UTR3    MET10
UTR3    METTL7A
UTR3    MET10
```

Result:

final

```
Site      Gene       df1       df2      df3
UTR3      KIAA1143   NA        NA       df3
UTR3      AAK1       NA        NA       df3
UTR3      ZNF154     df1       df2      NA
UTR3      MET10      df1       NA       NA
UTR3      MET10      NA        df2      NA
UTR3      MET10      NA        NA       df3
```

......... (the table continues)

As you can see, MET10 is present in all samples, but the code is not giving the correct result!

I would expect the following:

```
Site      Gene       df1       df2      df3
UTR3      KIAA1143   NA        NA       df3
UTR3      AAK1       NA        NA       df3
UTR3      ZNF154     df1       df2      NA
UTR3      MET10      df1       df2      df3
```

......... (the table continues)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

lst(df1,df2,df3) %>%
  bind_rows(.id='df') %>%
  filter(V1 %in% unique(V1[duplicated(V1)])) %>%
  mutate(df2=df) %>%
  spread(df,df2)

#   V1  df1 df2 df3
# 1  A  df1 df2 df3
# 2  B  df1 df2 df3
# 3  G <NA> df2 df3
# 4  H <NA> df2 df3
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
A
B
C
D")

df2 <- read.table(header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
A
B
G
H")

df3 <- read.table(header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
A
B
G
H")
```

Comment: This works, but I modified it a little bit. I see that some values in the coulmn "V1" are not showing even if they are present in multiple tables(4 tables). I think this is because there are values that are duplicated inside one table (for example A A A B C, it is not showing all A A A as common to multiple files, even if they are!). Maybe it is because I can't choose a column name instead of "V1"

Comment: that's surprising. If you can synthetize this issue in a minimal reproductible example and edit your question I'll take a look.

Comment: I exemplified using your code(that mostly do work, but something is weird in the results)